# I use my mic as microphone and connects with wireless device but there is 2 sec lags coming on swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create an iOS app which play live audio over bluetooth speaker. For that first I record an audio then after that I play that sound and repeat this process. But while playing live audio i am getting 2 sec lag. So can some one help me to solve this or give some alternate solution.

Thanks in advance

Below is my code.

```
@IBAction func micClick(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        
        if bluetoothAudioConnected() {
            if micSwitch.isOn {
                startSpeakerTimer()
            } else {
                if micRecored != nil {
                    micRecored.stop()
                    micRecored = nil
                }
            }
        } else {
            showToast(controller: self, message: "Please connect to bluetooth speaker first." , seconds: 2)
            self.micSwitch.setOn(false, animated: false)
        }
    }

func startSpeakerTimer() {
        let currentDateTime = Date().string(format: "YYYY-MM-dd_HH:mm")
        let fileName = "recording" + currentDateTime + ".m4a"
        print("File Name : \(currentDateTime)")
        let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        micFilePath = audioFilename
        print("FileName\(audioFilename)")

        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 5000,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        ]

        do {
            
            micRecored = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioFilename, settings: settings)
            micRecored.delegate = self
            micRecored.record()
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(500), execute: {
                do {
                    
                    if (self.micRecored != nil) {
                        self.micRecored.stop()
                        self.micRecored = nil
                        
                        self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: self.micFilePath)
                        self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                        self.audioPlayer?.play()
                        
                        let fileManager = FileManager.default
                        do {
                            try fileManager.removeItem(at: self.micFilePath)
                        } catch {
                            print("Exception")
                        }
                        if self.micSwitch.isOn {
                            self.startSpeakerTimer()
                        }
                    }
                    
                } catch {
                    if self.micSwitch.isOn {
                        self.startSpeakerTimer()
                    }
                    print("Error in play audio :  \(error)")
                }
            })
        } catch {
            print("Exception")
            showToast(controller: self, message:"Error in start recording" , seconds: 2)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing on at least two bluetooth devices? Have you ruled out that this is a hardware issue?

Comment: Yes already tested on multiple bluetooth devices. It's not hardware issue